# EditText align digits to background image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an EditText using the image below as the background image.

[image]

The EditText is numeric only, and is limited to 6 digits long.  On some devices, the digits line up perfectly in each slot, however I can not find a way to make it consistent across devices.  On larger screen and high density devices, the digits do not line up, and end of being in the middle of a divider.  The layout that contains the EditText is using a Weight attribute to allow it to scale correctly across devices.  Can anyone suggest a method I can use to make the digits always line up in the slots of the background image - regardless of the screen size/density?

Any suggestions/examples would be GREATLY appreciated!!!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 6 different EditText views with each view containing only one digit. When user input some value in first view just change the focus to the second one to make typing the values easy.
You can also handle backspace button to taking focus back to views before.

You could use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for listen inputing events on each EditText

Comment: Too much for what I need to do, some I'm just removing the background image.  Your answer is the only thing that makes sense though, so I've marked it as correct.